# Best way to animate elements passing through viewport in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, css, animation, graphics, gsap

I have a set of elements, set next to each each in a row. The number, scale, etc of these is dynamic. I would like them to pass from one side to the other on the screen in an infinite loop, so as one element leaves the one side it comes in again on the opposite, like this:

[image]

[Here is a Codepen Illustrating the above example](http://codepen.io/mileso/pen/rryAxN). Imagine the black box is the viewport, so you can't see outside of it.

```
What is the easiest way to implement this conveyor belt/treadmill approach?
```

I've tried several ways of implementing this but am stuck finding a reliable, smooth, and flexible solution to what seems like a very simple problem. I've hit a wall, how would you do this?

I'm just looking for the concept, library, etc.

Could a GreenSock library work well for this?

If this is too ambiguous could anyone point me toward a more appropriate place to ask?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if it fits your situation but the recent update to **GSAP** i.e. the **[1.19.0](http://greensock.com/1-19-0/)** brings a few features that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: [This is simple using GSAP's modifiers plugin](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16952-modifiers-plugin-for-infinite-image-carousel/?tab=comments#comment-109740).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what makes you say it *"seems like a very simple problem"*, because (for me) it clearly isn't. Let's break it down:

1. Make the conveyor belt move (I'm assuming you move the belt container for this).
2. Trigger whenever an element completely left the screen.
3. Move that element in DOM at the other end of the belt and simultaneously adjust the belt position so the change in DOM is not visible in the belt animation, which should remain smooth.

This is how I'd go for it, but there are chances that the animation might stagger/flicker when the change in DOM is made, especially if you have other animations running in the page at the same time. If this happens, you might want to clone elements instead of moving them and only delete the originals after the rendering of the clone is finished. It might *"seem"* (sic) like the same thing, but the browser will do them one after the other instead of in the same time. It sometimes helps.

I'm a curious guy by nature so I'm already planning on making a fiddle with this at the end of the day. If I find anything notable or if I come up with another approach I'll update.

Comment: I like this idea, as long as the elements are left in DOM and only the translate3d of the parent belt and child element are changed, IMO performance should be good. My understanding is that you have it backwards, adding/removing elements in DOM is expensive, but changing properties isn't as much, esp when hardware acceleration is enabled with translate3d. Stayingn in `window.requestAnimationFrame` as well, jumping/skipping should be minimized. But that has been the main issue I've encountered with most implementations so it is absolutely a concern.  I'll update this with a new Codepen shortly.

Comment: Just keep in mind, for simplicity, the size/number/speed of these elements is constant but in the final form of this,  they will be very dynamic, so sometimes skipping comes into play only when the speed or element count are at specific values. So it needs to be able to handle the elements getting thinner and changing in other ways while moving. Shouldn't change the principle of how it works though.